# If statement works without else statement. I added else statement and now if doesn't work, even though the results are true

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have listed my code below and I would appreciate any help that could be provided.  I'm trying to get this script to look at a text file for usernames, look in a directory for folders that match the usernames and move them if they exist.  That all works fine without the `else` statement.  When I add the `else` statement to output "No Folders Found", meaning the `if` statement returned false. The `if` statement is skipped even though the folders exist.

```
$text = Get-Content "\\servername\sharename\H Drive Moves\HDrive_Folders.txt"
$Dir = Get-Childitem "\\servername\sharename"
$FromDir = "\\servername\sharename"
$ToDir = "\\servername\sharename"
$Transcript = "\\servername\c$\Scripts\Output\Moves_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).txt"
$FNF = ' "NO FOLDERS FOUND" '
$DelMsg = ' "DELETED FROM HOME SUCCESSFULLY" '
$MoveMsg = ' "MOVED TO FUF SUCCESSFULLY" '

foreach ($item in $text) {
  foreach ($folder in $Dir) {
    if ($folder -like $item) {
      Start-Transcript -Path $Transcript -Append
      Copy-Item $FromDir\$item $ToDir -Recurse -Force
      Write-Host "$item $MoveMsg"
      Remove-Item "$FromDir\$item" -Recurse -Force
      Write-Host "$item $DelMsg" 
      Stop-Transcript
    } else {
      Start-Transcript -Path $Transcript -Append
      Write-Host $FNF
      Stop-Transcript
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `$folder` and `$item` for a supposed match?

Comment: I was trying to get the script to look at the names of folders from a text file and search a directory for those folder names.  It is then supposed to find a match and move the folder.  It does that without the else statement but I want the script to output an error message if there are no folders found in the directory, even though there are folder names in the text file.

Comment: $folder - Is supposed to reference all folders in a directory | 
$item - is supposed to reference each folder name that is in a text file

Comment: I wasn't asking what their values are supposed to be, but what their *actual* values are when they are supposed to match.